# Java modulus concept - arithmetic definition (a/b)*b+(a%b)

Tags: java, definition, modulo, modulus

I have recently started learning code (Java), and have looked up the modulus operator on the Oracle website, as per the section 15.17.3. of the following link:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3

Basically, if `a` is the denominator, and `b` is the nominator, it states that: `(a/b) * b + (a%b) = a`, which defines the modulus operator as:  `a%b = a – (a/b) * b`.

I am confused because the equation simply does not work, which can be simplified as `a%b = 0`. I know my basic math algebra, so I am hoping if someone can enlighten me on how is it supposed to equal?

Comment: There is no modulo operator in Java. It is a [remainder operator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.3).

Answer (score 1):

For integers, operator `/` means integral division, not mathematical one, for example:

```
7/2 = 3
6/2 = 3
5/2 = 2
4/2 = 2
3/2 = 1
2/2 = 1
1/2 = 0
```

In math terms, formula from java spec will be written like:

```
⌊a/b⌋ * b + (a%b) = a
a%b = a – ⌊a/b⌋ * b
```

Comment: Nice use of floor math symbol, but I believe that `⌊x⌋` is `Math.floor(x)`, which rounds towards negative infinity, while `a/b` rounds towards `0`. As long as `a` and `b` are positive, you're good though, and who in their right mind tries modulus on negative numbers anyway.

Comment: That last equation really makes sense when you think about what the remainder operator actually does, and it's relationship with integral division.

Comment: @Lashane, Thanks that was exactly the missing knowledge that I needed to understand the equation. problem solved :)